React отображает по разному два приложения с одинаковой src папкой. Как можно посмотреть логи? Что не подгрузилось?
Есть приложение. Нужно вытащить из него одну страницу отдельно. Создал для этого новое приложение. Скопировал папку src туда, установил все модули. В исходном приложении есть страница:

При этом в новом приложении она выглядит так:

Файлы я не менял и не удалял. Однако в новом проекте одинаковые по содержанию src отображается по другому. В node js в обоих приложениях ошибок нет, но одно из них явно не подгрузило какие-то стили. Можно ли каким-то debug tool найти в чем причина?

Я не вижу разницы между скринами... однако сверять придется глазками в отладчике, либо, если стили прописаны через переменные, можно законсолить, но придется пересобрать 2 приложения..

@SwaD ну я лично увидел разницу в конпке внизу.

@OliverPatterson А, точно )
